# How to know the format when programmatically setting a field value

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to create a set of entities based on a CSV file on install of a custom module. The entity has a price field and I don't know how to find out what I should be passing in as a value, the following does not work:

```
$entity = entity_create('item_price', ['type' => 'wand']);
$entity->setName('Harry Potter');
$entity->set('price', 2000);
$entity->save();
```

Although this problem is specific to the price field I would like to know as a general rule **how does one "discover" what format the value should be in for any field type**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass price object to it and not just a number. Do like this -

```
$price = new Price('2000', 'USD');
$entity->set('price', $price);
$entity->save();
```

You can always look at tests to know how things are working for the module. :)

Comment: But an array works too, how do you know what to use? How do you inspect a field type to find out what is required?

Comment: I think you are saying about this price field in terms of a product variation. If you would go to ProductVariationInterface.php in product module inside commerce module. Then navigate to function setPrice(). And that method takes Price object as an argument. This is how I decide what to use. :)